# How to create Multiple Storyboards in IOS and how to connect them

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am a newbie programmer in iOS and I am using a Mac mini with Mountain Lion with xcode 5.x.

I want to create an iOS application, which is really big in terms of user interfaces. So working with storyboard is difficult for me. I want to create one *MainStoryboard* and several other storyboards, connect them in such a way that they can run together in a sequence or in particular order.

Is this possible, if yes guide me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't push or present new storyboards from IB, but you can and load it in this way:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
//Or use UIViewController* viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Storyboard_ID"];
```